# Preventing default views with RESTful api in CakePHP

Tags: json, cakephp, rest

I am following the [tutorial in the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1239/The-Simple-Setup) that explains the basics of setting up a RESTful web service.

So far, I've updated my routes file to the following:

```
Router::mapResources('stores');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

I have also setup a blank layout in app/layouts/json and the appropriate json views. I am receiving my json output successfully when I navigate to controller/action.json

I am wondering though, without the.json extension it attempts to load the regular view. I am looking to build a pure api with only json output, is there any way to prevent regular render output instead?

Answer (score 6):

You could force a rendering as JSON if you can recognise a JSON request another way.  For example, if the Accepts HTTP header contains application/json, you could put this in your controller:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    if ($this->request->accepts('application/json')) {
        $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
    }
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

It's CakePHP 2.0 notation, but something similar probably exists for CakePHP 1.2 and 1.3.

You could also detect the request Content-Type instead, or as well, especially if Accepts is not used.

Comment: Thx. I got it working by omitting the "if" and only did:
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
parent::beforeFilter();

Answer (score 0):

What are you seeing at the moment? If you've used bake Cake may have generated the views for you?

Just delete the views in `/app/views/layout` and `/app/views/controllername`

If you are trying to prevent the request from hitting the controller at all then I'm not so sure, you could just update your .htaccess file to only send requests ending in .json to the app or something similar.

Comment: I have removed the views from each of these locations and all I have is my json folders. But cake gives me a missing view error when I navigate to a controller without the .json after the action.

Comment: Well you could update .htaccess so apache only rewrites requests that match *.json

Comment: I did consider that, thought that Cake may have a way to lock it down if your building a pure api.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i did.

if i know i'm building only json API, i added to my AppController.php following:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    if (empty($this->request->params['ext']) || $this->request->params['ext'] != "json")
    {
        $this->render(FALSE, 'maintenance'); //no view, only layout
        $this->response->send();
        $this->_stop();
    }
}
```

and in my /app/Layouts/maintenance.ctp

```
echo __('Invalid extension');
```

this way all requests without the json extension will end up on the "maintenance" page where you can put any info you want, i'm planning to put there link to API docs.